# html <ul> <li> tags - inline display

Tags: html, css

Within the html file, I have a list set up as:

```
<div id="sep1">
       <ul>
         <li><img id="rm_img_1" src="images/remove.png"></li>
         <li id="rm_txt_1">Remove Section</li>
       </ul>
</div>
```

The image inside the link has width and height of 25px. Within the CSS I have:

```
#sep1 ul li {
    display:inline;}

#rm_img_1{
    padding-top:0px;
    padding-right:5px;
    padding-left:5px;}

#rm_txt_1{
    padding-top:0px;
    padding-left:5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;}
```

The text is not inline with the image tough I have cut all around the image. How can I put the text and image horizontally aligned?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

in `#rm_img_1`

That should align them both.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ypov8r84/

Answer (score 0):

Based on a 400x400px photo , You must have the same width for each li.
So replace with this

`#sep1 ul li {
    display:inline-block; width: 400px; text-align:center;}`

here's : http://jsfiddle.net/daz3dg53/